# Stability of Ninject.Mvc and Ninject.Wcf extensions

Tags: ioc-container, ninject, idisposable, ninject-2, ninject-extensions

I'm planning to start using Ninject 2.2 in enterprise-like project after playing with it for some time. Can anyone confirm no issues with these extensions in production use? I especially worry about `IDisposable` scenarios (client WCF proxies in MVC controllers, etc).

Comment: Can you give more detail on the scenario you're worrying about? Lots of peoplle can understand specifics. Few feel need to answer vague questions with carte blanche answers which wouldnt help anyone...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We consider 2.2 as stable. If you find a bug we try to fix it fast.